# When using pdb, is there a way to have automated commands run on startup?

Tags: python, pdb

When I'm trying to debug Python code with `pdb`, many times I want use `pprint` to parse through outputs in a human readable way. So far, I've just been running `from pprint import pprint` as soon as `pdb` starts up. This works fine for one-off scenarios, but can get a bit annoying if I'm jumping in and out of the debugger frequently.

Is there a way I could automate this such that `pprint` is already available for me as soon as `pdb` is invoked via something like `pdb.set_trace()`?

Comment: What IDE do you use? If it is pycharm or VS you can use have installed an internal plugin for debugging.

Comment: I'm using VS -- any recommendation on an internal plugin for debugging to look into?